# Redirect non-www to www and http to https://www in Nginx reverse proxy?

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am attempting to use Nginx to redirect both www and non www, in http or https to land on `https://www`

I've tried variations on the sites-enabled file but non-www doe snot seem to redirect correctly so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

My sites-enabled file looks like this (obviously with actual IP and a real domain name)

```
upstream wwwweb_be {
        server 111.11.11.111:443;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.web.co.uk web.co.uk;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl:
        server_name web.co.uk;
        return 301 https://www.web.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        server_name www.web.co.uk;
        ssl_certificate /etc/sslcerts/web.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/sslcerts/web.co.uk/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/wwwweb_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/wwwweb_error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://wwwweb_be;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        }
}
```

This seems to happily direct the https://www. and the http://www to the complete `https://www.web.co.uk` website without issue, anything to do with `http://web.co.uk` or `https://web.co.uk` doesn't work.

Where am I gong wrong? To confirm, wether it come in as www or without www, in http or https, it needs to end on `https://www.web.co.uk`

Comment: Test your website using `curl -I` for each of the four cases. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files. The second `server` block is missing any ssl certificates.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for your response, I had somehow missed it!  

When you say the second server is missing an SSL certificate.  I'm a little confused at that point, I only have one server and that is www.web.co.uk there is no server for the non www one?  This isn't something I've usually had to work with so it's causing me some confusion

Comment: You have three `server {}` blocks providing responses to two domains using two protocols (four cases). In order to redirect from `https://non-www` to www, the server must first accept a request to the non-www server. So you have **two** servers listening on port 443, one provides your website and the other provides a return 301. Both need a valid certificate (usually the same certificate - as the alt-names often list both the non-www and www names of the domain).